# Tkinter percentage sizes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a small software with the Tkinter module and python but I can't figure out how to set a widget size with percentages instead of pixels. I could of course do it by grabbing the size of the entire window at every moment and divide by 2 to get a size of 50%, but is there a better way to do it with the Tkinter module?

EDIT 1: To answer your questions I put my code here:

```
class Navbar:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.maxsizeFrame = Frame(master, height = 50) #maxsize handler, prevent self.frame to grow too big
        self.maxsizeFrame.pack(fill = X, expand = NO)
        self.frame = Frame(self.maxsizeFrame)
        self.frame.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = YES)
        self.masteries = Button(self.frame, text = "Masteries")
        self.masteries.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = YES)
        self.runes = Button(self.frame, text = "Runes")
        self.runes.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH, expand = YES)
```

So I want to create a navigation bar with two button handled in "self.frame". But I want this design to be responsive, that's why I set expand to "YES". However I wanted to set a maximum size for "self.frame" but the only way I found was to pack this frame in an other one ("self.maxsizeFrame") and set expand to "NO" on this one. And finally, I would like to set the maximum expand size to half the main window, so it could be great if the height of "self.maxsizeframe" could be in percentage. Thanks for reading.

EDIT 2: 
Actually it seems more efficient to build the software with the grid layout and the weight's option would be accurate.

Comment: there are ways, but we need more details. Using a percentage size is unusual. Do you want to do it for every widget, or just one widget? Which widget or widgets do you want to use? Can you create a simple [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to make it half the size of the window, use `width=root.winfo_width / 2, height=winfo_height`
In the maximum size. (I had to post it late due to the limit of posting per 30Mins

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I wonder how no one responded yet.
So instead of sizing the component at the moment of creation, you can instead use the `widget.place()` method, define `relwidth` and `relheight` (0=0%,0.5=50%,1=100%,etc), this will give the widget x% of its parent width/height. Using place() you can also define relative starting positions for the widgets using `relx` and `rely`, and even apply `width`,`height`,`x`, and `y` by specifying screen units as you would do normally.

Now the fun stuff, which I don't see talked around, is that you can apply `relwidth` and `width` at the same time,by playing with negative values and joining `relx` and `x` properties, you can get really responsive sites.

Here is an example where I played a bit with this fields to get the responsiveness I've desired:(don't mind 'yposition' comes from the application context)

```
self.label.place(rely=yposition,x=0.025,relheight=0.04,width=150)   
self.entry.place(rely=yposition,x=150,relheight=0.04,relwidth=0.95,width=-190)
self.button.place(rely=yposition,relx=0.98,x=-40,relheight=0.04,width=40)
```

Answer (score -2):

Although it depends on the widget, you should be able to do `width=30%` and same with height. Can you please edit your post saying which widget you are using. I would not recommend percents though as they get funky some times.

Comment: % symbol doesn't work with width and height, can you show any code?